# solr data-import search

Tags: solr, data-import

I am new to solr. I want to search database. I am able to import the values and index it.but while searching it seems the field name is necessary to mention in the search query.how can it be done without specifying the field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import all data into the **[default field](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml)**. Then you don't need to explicitly mention the field names. (Although you still can if you want)

The default `schema.xml` with Solr already contains an example for using such a "catchall" field:

First the field has to be declared like any other field:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true"
       stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Then this new field has to be declared the default field. Whenever no specific field is searched, this one will be searched:

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

You also need some `copyField` statements which copy all existing fields into the catchall field:

```
<copyField source="cat" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="my_special_field_1" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="my_special_field_2" dest="text"/>
...
```

So whenever the field `my_special_field_1` is indexed its value is *also* added to the `text` field.

As a shortcut you can copy all fields into the `text` field with

```
<copyField source="*" dest="text"/>
```

After that you can perform searches without specifying any field.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I just want to confirm that if i copy all the fields will that cause a performance issue. I mean due to copyfield are the values stored twice.

Comment: It will increase the size of your index but not the search time (in comparison to explicitly stating all fields in your query) Also since the `stored` parameter is false, the original data is not stored, so the increase of the index should be moderate.

Comment: thank you again. Last but not least I have three different tables, all having different field names, after indexing and searching i am getting list of search results. from here how can i distinguish different table records?

Comment: Simply add another field of type `string` and fill it with the name of the original table.